# Why FreeRTOS requires stop once in a breakpoint to run well?

Tags: embedded, breakpoints, freertos, zynq-ultrascale+

I have an application for Zynq MPSoC (Vitis 2020.2) written in C++ using FreeRTOS V10.3.0. This application runs very well if stops at a breakpoint once. If I disable all breakpoints program runs buggy? What might be problem?

Comment: This seems to be a timing issue. Do you have multi threading ? Are the threads accessing shared data ? Have you used mutex for shared data access ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How many ways could this happen?!  It is a real-time operating system, presumably then also a real-time application.  If you stop the coprocessor you affect the timing.  Without knowing the hardware, the software, where you are placing the breakpoint and the bugs that arise when free-running, it is not possible to answer your specific question. I.e. you need to debug it - there is no generic explanation as to why the intrusive action of stopping the processor "fixes" *your* system.

You clearly have buggy code that is affected by timing.  Stopping the code does not necessarily stop peripherals and it certainly does not stop the outside world that your system interacts with.   For example when you stop on a breakpoint, the world continues, interrupts become pending (possibly several), so that when you resume execution, the execution path and thread scheduling order is likely to differ considerably from that when it is free-run as all those pending interrupts are handled and in turn issue events that cause different tasks to become pending ready-to-run and then run in a different order to that which would otherwise occur.

Ultimately you are asking the wrong question; the breakpoint is not magically "fixing" your code, rather it is significantly changing the way that it runs such that some existing bug (or bugs) is hidden or avoided.  The bug is still there, so the question would better focus on finding the bug than "magic thinking".

The bugs could be at any level, but most likely are design issues with inappropriate task partitioning, priority assignment, IPC, task synchronisation or resource protection.  Generally probably rather too broad to deal with in a single SO question.